# Create a group on openfire from an Android app

Tags: java, android, openfire, smack, asmack

I developed a chat application (Android platform, native Android development) using asmack library. Also I have a task to create from the application group in openfire server. I don't know how to do it.

And also additional question: is it possible or not?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the Openfire REST API plugin, which allow you to create new groups over REST/HTTP e.g. from your application.

Look here: https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/restapi/readme.html#create-a-group

Answer (score 0):

However this question is old and already answered, I am adding for the peoples which are still looking for quick and easy solution.
I have written a client library and have used in one of my project. Library is available on github -https://github.com/xibsked/Openfire-Rest-Api-Client-Android